# How does a Legendary weapon with a Radiation effect calculate Damage?

Tags: fallout-4

Today I was playing Fallout 4 when I suddenly found a legendary enemy which dropped a laser rifle with 50 damage per extra case radiation, but then I proved I couldn't see the difference between this laser rifle and a normal rifle.

How does radiation damage work?

Comment: Please consider adding some screenshots and additional info backing up your comparison to help clarify your question.

Comment: The quotient would be 50/total damage. So if the gun dpes 200 damage + 50 radiation damage, 20% of the damage will be radiation. Radiation is a damage type new to Fallout 4. How it works should not be difficult to answer, if it has not already been asked, before.

Comment: @Timelord64 actually radiation damage is quite complicated in FO4, especially when it comes to the gamma gun.  There's a whole wiki page dedicated to it.

Comment: What do you mean you "proved" you "couldn't see the difference"?

Answer (score 2):

All "Irradiated" legendary weapons deal radiation poisoning in addition to their normal damage.

Radiation poisoning (from [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Radiation#Fallout_4)) functions exactly like environmental radiation: each 1 point of radiation poisoning reduces max health by .1% (so 50 points of rad poisoning reduces max health by 5%). This gets reflected as actual damage, even if a character is at full health. Moreover, since this directly affects maximum health, this is damage that can't be healed: even legendary enemy mutations or the "resethealth" console command will restore health only up to any limits from radiation poisoning.

Comment: I'm assuming that ghouls (possible super mutants as well) are actually healed by radiation damage instead?

Comment: Ghouls have very high radiation resistance, so they are nearly immune to a radiation weapon.  Super mutants are immune to radiation poisoning, but not actual radiation damage.